# Menu items changing color according to position of element

Tags: javascript, menu, position, menuitem

My page is divided into three sections and each section can be accessed by respective menu item. I am trying to achieve this in Javascript: when the user has reached any of the sections by scrolling, the font color of respective menu item should change.

Here I call the function:

```
<body onscroll="detectScroll(); showPosition();">
```

This is the function that detects scrolling and changes some items accordingly. It's working fine:

```
function detectScroll() { 
    var header = document.querySelector(".headerOrig"),
        header_height  = getComputedStyle(header).height.split('px')[0],
        header_class = "changeHeader",
        logo = document.getElementById("logo")
        ;

    if( window.pageYOffset > (parseInt(header_height) + 500)) {     
        header.classList.add(header_class);
        logo.src = "images/logo2.png";
    }
    if( window.pageYOffset < (parseInt(header_height) + 500)) {
        header.classList.remove(header_class);
        logo.src = "images/logo1.png";
    }
}
```

This JS function returns the position of an element. Works fine as well:

```
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

And, finally, this is the JS function that is being called when scrolling:

```
function showPosition() {
    var myElement = document.getElementById("posBIKES"); 
    var position = getPosition(myElement);
    var bike = document.getElementById("bikesMenu");
    //alert("The element is located at: " + position.x + ", " + position.y);
    if(window.pageYOffset < position.y) {
        window.getElementById("bikesMenu").classList.remove("changeMenu");
    }
    if(window.pageYOffset > position.y) {
        window.getElementById("bikesMenu").classList.add("changeMenu");
    }
}
```

The problem is everything works fine until I try to add or remove the class to the item selected (the last function). Any other statement works fine, for example, I tried putting alert("something"); in both conditions and both worked as desired. Whats wrong with adding and removing classes then?
And yes, I have checked the corresponding names and IDs of everything like million times, so theres no issue with that. 
Any help is more than appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see an obvious mistake. Does the browser support classList?(IE>9) Perhaps you could set up a jsfiddle for us to try it.